# how to display only one output ("Recognized, OK") when I say a 2-syllable word or more

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition

I just want my program to say "Recognized, OK!" if it hears words. Words that have either one or more syllable word.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeechRecognitionExample
  {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
          {
           private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognitionEngine;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += (s, args) =>
        {
            foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in args.Result.Words)
            {
                if (word.Confidence > 0.0f)
                    txtOutput.Text += "Recognized, OK!";
            }
            txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        };
        recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Please help me. Thank you. Because when I say a word that has two or three syllable it displays "Recognized, OK!" two or three times too. But if I say, example, "START" it just returns 1 output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, if there's any word. The program should say "Recognized, OK!"?

If that, use this:

```
recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += (s, args) =>
    {

        if (!args.Result.Words.Any() && word.Confidence <= 0.0f) return;

        txtOutput.Text += "Recognized, OK!";
        txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    };
```

Comment: so I'll omit the word confidence?

Comment: Did you just copy - paste the code from other? `args.Result.Words.Any()`